# In AHK, how can I create a new Chrome browser window and activate it

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I would like to create a new Chrome window with the following AutoHotKey script:

```
#c::
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Default",,,PID
  WinWait New Tab
  WinMove, New Tab,, 225,40, 1400, 900
  #WinActivateForce
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
return
```

Although Chrome always runs as expected, this *does not* reliably *activate* the newly created Chrome window: Sometimes it is activated, sometimes it isn't (the original program of focus stays activated, or sometimes just Program Manager/Desktop). Sometimes it is placed on top of MS Word (or other MS software), sometimes it isn't placed on top.

It's just unreliable. Even if I sprinkle the script with `WinActivate`, it doesn't reliably activate the window:

```
#c::
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Default",,,PID
  WinWait New Tab
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
  WinMove, New Tab,, 225,40, 1400, 900
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
  #WinActivateForce
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
return
```

Adding various `Sleep` statements doesn't resolve the issue either:

```
#c::
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Default",,,PID
  WinWait New Tab
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
  WinMove, New Tab,, 225,40, 1400, 900
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
  Sleep, 1000
  #WinActivateForce
  WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
return
```

**How can I reliably activate the Chrome window I created?**

Comment: I think this is an issue with the keyboard hook interacting with Windows. You might be able to reliably get your window to activate if you press and hold your WinKey + C for about a full second or slightly longer. I've noticed that when I try things like this, that can make a difference whether an application gets the focus or not.

Answer (score 0):

Open the AHK application, right click on tray icon and click Open, and a console of a short will be shown. Run your shortcut and then click on the console and press `F5` to see what AHK is doing.

For example, when I run your shortcut with a fresh install of Chrome, it got stuck and *nothing* was working. It turns out, a fresh install defaults to the Google accounts signin page. So the `New Tab` is not there and AHK is sitting there waiting for it...

[image: AHK Status]

So, in the above you can see several attempts to run a modified version of your shortcut. They complete with the last statement executed is `Return`. But when I reset the start up page to anything else, AHK is stuck at the `WinWait` command shown above with the red arrow.

HTH

EDIT: Since Chrome adds the application name at the end of each tab, a better way to point to the window may be using a partial search like shown [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/18838-using-winwait-with-a-partial-name/).

Comment: Mine has no issue with "getting stuck", even when the Chrome window isn't activated the console does not hang at any point.

Comment: Also, sometimes there may be other Chrome windows open. I don't want any of the other ones to be activated by mistake by non-specifically using "Google Chrome" to select the window to activate.